# Is there any filter to add a custom attribute to the <body> tag in admin panel?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, admin

I don't need to add a class to the body tag. I need to add the ng-app attribute to the body tag.

It is needed on the body tag because I need to use multiple controllers in different metaboxes of post edit page.

Is there any way to do this?

If it is not possible in the body tag then is there any other preferable tag with a corresponding filter where I should add the ng-app attribute of angular JS?

Comment: You can do this with javascript/jquery - please include some code so that someone can show you how to go about doing so.  Alternatively, if you can edit the header.php file, you can just add the attribute there.

Comment: Some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790432/placement-of-the-ng-app-directive-html-vs-body